# How can I improve the speed of this EF code?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm filling the `trPerDay` dictionary with ~2700 values and it takes several seconds. Can these DB queries be optimized in some way?

```
        // transactions per day
        SortedDictionary<DateTime, int> trPerDay = new SortedDictionary<DateTime, int>();

        foreach (Order order in orders)
        {
            foreach (OrderDetail od in order.OrderDetails)
            {
                int qty = CommonUtils.ComputeQuantity(od);

                DateTime date = order.date.Date;

                if (!trPerDay.ContainsKey(date))
                {
                    trPerDay.Add(date, qty);
                }
                else
                {
                    trPerDay[date] += qty;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: First I would look at the DB. Where is the DB and if there is any latency between the DB and the application. Next I would create the proper DB indexes. Next I would try to do not bring back on the server an entire record when in fact I need only an ID or so. After these check the speed and the community will come back with many more optimizations.

Comment: What does `CommonUtils.ComputeQuantity` do? Can this also be calculated on the DB server based upon the values of `OrderDetails`?

Comment: In addition, a sample of your entities and of the DbContext would be helpful. The best way to speed this up is to perform the aggregation per date on the database server transferring only the result to the application server. In your sample you move all the detail rows to the application server and aggregate them there.

Comment: It sums up `OrderDetail.Quantity` with some exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to get order details count by date

```
orders.GroupBy(x => x.date.Date)
.Select(x => new { date = x.Key, list = x.ToList().Sum(y => y.OrderDetails.Sum(od => CommonUtils.ComputeQuantity(od))))})
```

Comment: Actually, I'm summing `OrderDetail.Quantity` with some exceptions. Can you rework your query for this purpose?

Comment: can you try new code

Comment: This is very bad as ToList() will materialize the query and download all orders from the database. Then for each order it will issue a new query to get the OrderDetails.

Comment: I'm using this and I have an "ambiguous invocation" issue on the Sum() statement: `orders.GroupBy(x => x.date.Date).Select(x => new { date = x.Key, list = x.ToList().Sum(y => y.OrderDetails.Sum(od => CommonUtils.ComputeQuantity(od))) })`

Answer (score 0):

At a bare minimum, when you load orders, be sure to eager load the OrderDetails to avoid a lazy load hit for each order. This assumes that your ComputeQuantity is prohibitively complex and cannot be expressed down into a Linq calculation.

If it is possible to compute the Quantity within a linq expression, the query performance can be drastically improved by doing a `GroupBy`. For example:

```
var quantitiesPerDay = _context.Orders
    .GroupBy(o => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(o.date))
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, 
        g.Sum(o => o.SelectMany(x => x.OrderDetails
            .Where(od => /* Linq logic to determine what to include */)
            .Quantity)));

var trPerDay = new SortedDictionary(quantitiesPerDay);
```

The catch here is that the logic to determine what order details to include has to be expressed in a `Where` expression without doing something like declaring a C# function to compute it. EF has to be able to translate the expression down to SQL. This may not look as "clean" as separating it off into a separate method, but the difference is allowing the database do do the computation is likely sub-second time vs. seconds or more (as the system grows in size) doing the computation in memory after fetching *all* applicable orders and order details into memory first.

Comment: I've an error even on this simplified version of the query: `var quantitiesPerDay = context.Orders.GroupBy(o => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(o.date))                .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g.Sum(o => o.SelectMany(x => x.OrderDetails.Quantity)));` the error is "the name 'g' does not exist in the current context" on the `g.Sum()` statement. Can you check please?

Comment: It might need to be `.ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.SelectMany(x => x.OrderDetails.Quantity).Sum())` Sorry, I don't really have a workable example project to test with, I may need to spin something up.

Comment: Hello. Even this one does not work: `var quantitiesPerDay = context.Orders
                .GroupBy(o => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(o.date))
                .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.SelectMany(x => x.OrderDetails.Quantity).Sum());` Quantity is marked in red/not defined.

Comment: ah.. should be `SelectMany(x => x.OrderDetails.Select(od => od.Quantity)).Sum()` to get the Quantity from each OrderDetail.